# Wordpress Multiple Domain Redirect Not Working

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have any problem on my wordpress site. My wordpress site's new domain is (ex:) "www.domain.com" and last domain is "www.domain2.com". I assigned new domain's nameserver address to old domain's nameserver address. But not working rewrite rule when entering old domain. My rule is:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain2.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.*)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://domain.com/hello/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: have you make sue that your migration is done properly ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy solution may be to put this at the top of your theme's `header.php` file:

```
<?php
Header( "HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently" );
Header( "Location: http://www.new_site.com");
?>
```

You could also do this conditionally based off the requested URI, so only certain URLs get redirected:

```
<?php
if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == 'certain url' ) {
    Header( "HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently" );
    Header( "Location: http://www.new_site.com");
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks your reply but I want to select request url. For example if(requestUrl == "http://domain.com") {Header( "Location: http://www.new_site.com");} . Do you understand?